# Multi-parameter fit with constraints using R programming language

Tags: r, constraints, data-fitting

I have a set of experimental data (Exp) that I want to fit to a linear combination of 3 different models (M1, M2, M3), so that

```
Exp(1) =  a*M1(1) + b*M2(1) + c*M3(1)
Exp(2) =  a*M1(2) + b*M2(2) + c*M3(2)
...
Exp(N) =  a*M1(N) + b*M2(N) + c*M3(N)
```

thus, I want to derive the unknown a, b and c coefficients. These coefficients must represent the proportion of each model that best fit the experimental data, so I need to impose these constraints:

```
a + b + c = 1
0 < a < 1
0 < b < 1
0 < c < 1
```

From my little knowledge with R programming, I know how to do the easy fit without constraints. Something like:

```
library(xlsx)
mydata <- read.xlsx("data.xlsx", 1)
attach(mydata)
fiteq <- lm(Exp ~ M1 + M2 + M3)
summary(fiteq)
```

Could you please comment on how could I impose my constraints on the fit?

Thank you

Comment: google `constrained least squares in R`

Comment: `lpSolve` package does linear programming

Comment: So, did the values of the unconstrained problem satisfy the constraints? If not (and the sum-to-unity constraint would seem unlikely to be met)  how far were they off for the inequality constraints? And what did you find when you did searching?